sending token in all requests in nextjs external api calls
iam using nextjs14 as my frontend and iam using axios to perform api calls to my backend
here is my axios Instance:
import axios from "axios";
import { apiBaseURL, webBaseURL } from "config";
import { getCookie } from "cookies-next";

export const axiosServerBase = axios.create({
    baseURL: apiBaseURL,
    timeout: 30000,
    headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${getCookie("user") && JSON.parse(getCookie("user") as string).token}`,
    },
});

and iam using it in my API folder under the app
here is my example request
import { axiosServerBase } from "config";

export async function POST(request: Request): Promise<Response> {
    console.log(request.headers);

    try {
        const body = await request.json();

        const { data } = await axiosServerBase.post(
            "/templates/save-email-template",
            {
                data: body,
            }
        );

        return Response.json({ status: 200, data });
    } catch (error: any) {
        return Response.json({
            status: 400,
            message: error.response.data.message,
        });
    }
}


for some reason i have to extract the token from the headers via this line
request.headers?.get("authorization")
and send it manually in the headers however it is set in the axios instance
my question:

is it right to set the authorization manually in every request?
and if not what should i do?


You don't have to manually set an Authorization in the header in every request since you already created an instance with axios.create, you should only do that if you want to overwrite the default Authorization with another for just a particular request.

that what i thought but when i try to log the token in the backend i got it undefined if i did not include it again manually in the serverSide call in nextjs

It also depends on where you are calling the function, if you are calling it in on the server using getServerSideProps for instance, you won't be able to access the data in your cookie because they only exist on the client side. Try calling the function in the useEffect hook, that runs on the client side.
